# Returning Research Fellowship funding

Tags: mathematics, united-states, funding

I'm doing a PhD in the US and I got a research fellowship for a month this summer. I have done some work, but I'm not satisfied with it. There was no motivation and I haven't studied as much as I should have. Because of ethical reasons I want to return the money. Is it possible to do this in theory?

Comment: I'm very confused and at a point to change my field radically

Comment: What you may need at the moment is a break. A vacation. A chance to clear out the cruft.

Comment: @Buffy I did that already, but it wasn't helpful. My main thought is to leave math and I'm not sure how to make it ethically, because I believe that people around, including adviser have expectations. I made some promises when I had motivation(or rather I was hoping that motivation will restore). I might need to ask here a separate question for this.

Comment: at least I'm still at the beginning of my phD so I'm not burning so much bridges

Comment: Never mind the bridges. You need to do right by yourself. Maybe you need a long talk with your advisor. Math research can be very frustrating. Especially so if the problem you tackle isn't "ripe" for advancement. I've been there, and switching problems was the solution. But I was smart enough to recognize early on that the problem had no edges or cracks or anything that would permit entry. Some problems are, at a given time, perfectly impenetrable. Some have taken a century for solution.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks for your advice. I will think over this issue for some more time and then talk to advisor.

Comment: I do not consider myself an expert, but are not most fellowships structured as a contract between the government and the university?  You are not formally part of the contract.

Answer (score 7):

Quite a lot of funded projects are unsuccessful, though few may be willing to admit it. Whether you can return the money is up to the funding agency. I'd guess that few of them would require it, absent outright fraud, and many might not even be prepared to do it.

But, if you really want to do this, contact someone, such as a "program officer" at the funding agency and ask for "options". If the university was involved in accepting/managing the funding, as is typical, then first contact the program officer at the university and explain your qualms.

It is possible, also, that your "not being satisfied with it" is a function of your own high standards. Moreover, a month is hardly an indicator of much of anything in math research.

---

I assume you need to write a final report as part of the funding. Describe that the ideas proved fruitless and little or no progress was made (assuming that is true). Many people would consider this situation as a reason for requesting additional funding, by the way. "There is more to do here. Send $$$ to ...".

Comment: +1, especially for "a month is hardly an indicator of much of anything in math research."